# Find a linear map $f_{\theta}: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2$ which describes rotation by $\theta$ in counterclockwise direction

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

$\theta \in [0, 2\pi).$

> Hint: for a given angle $\theta$, find $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R$ such that $f_{\theta}(x_1, x_2) = (ax_1 + bx_2, cx_1 + dx_2).$

This problem occurs at the end of a chapter on the basics of complex numbers(very basic stuff like the definition of complex numbers). I googled the problem and it looks like the problem is meant to illustrate

[image: Geometric multiplication of complex numbers]

I tried this:

If $z, w$ are complex numbers, then:

$$zw$$
$$= r_1r_2e^{i(\theta_1+\theta_2)}$$
$$= r_1r_2(\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + i\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2))$$
$$= r_1(r_2\cos(\theta_1 + \theta_2) + r_2i\sin(\theta_1 + \theta_2))$$
$$= r_1(x + yi)$$
$$= r_1x + r_1iy$$

so we let $a = r_1$ and $b = r_1i$.

If this is wrong, how can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the vector ${\bf i}$. Rotate it by $\theta^{\circ}$ anti-clockwise and where does it end up? Do the same for ${\bf j}$.

You want the matrix which takes the vectors $(1,0)^{\top}$ and $(0,1)^{\top}$ to the vectors you just found.

Comment: If we rotate ${\bf i}$ by $\theta^0$, it ends up at some point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta).$ Does that make sense?

Comment: Why $\theta^\circ{}$ instead of just $\theta$?

Comment: @user346738 That's exactly right. If you rotated ${\bf j}$ then you'd get $(-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$. These give the columns of you matrix.

Comment: @lastresort Why not?

Comment: @FlybyNight Because you want $\mathbf{i}$ to end up at $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ rather than $(\cos\theta^\circ{}, \sin\theta^\circ{})$.